# Meteor Spacebars {{#each}} counter and first/last tests

Tags: meteor, spacebars

Is there any way to implement the following logic with Meteor Spacebars?

**Pseudo-code, a mix of Meteor and [Django's forloop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#for):**

```
{{#each jobs}}
    {{>jobItem }}
    {#if not forloop.last }}<hr>{{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: This should be made possible natively with Meteor - please vote on [this issues](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2587). The canonical way to do it is discussed on [meteor-talk](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/XSX1wgeZ06U/Cr5zOQV805UJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unforunately `{{each}}` doesn't do index. So you kind of have to pass back more info to the item to get it the info you would need. For instance this can put the index into your return object as another field.

```
var returnArray = _.map(divisions, function(item, key) {
  return _.extend(item, {
    "index": key
  });
});
```

Considering you just want the last one though, you might just want to append one attribute to the last one in your jobs. Create a helper function that just returns something like

```
return _.extend(_.last(Jobs.find().fetch(), {"last": true})
```

Then you can just have a `{{#if last}}{{else}}<hr>{{/if}}`. This way all the items that don't have the value get the hr, and your one that does have a last value, won't.

You could probably also take care of it in CSS.

```
hr:last-of-type { display: none }
```

You might have to double check the syntax on that.

Comment: Can you please add a closing bracket to '_.extend(_.last(Jobs.find().fetch() ->), {"last": true})'?

Comment: actually the line with extend is probably wrong even; That line will return only one object, which surely is not intended behavior -> template expects array of objects

Comment: Now `each` has an attribute called `@index`.